# Add event listeners based on CSS styles?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add different event listeners based on certain style conditions being met on an element. Is there a way I can check the style values and add event listeners that way? I have searched the internet and on here, but I have not found an answer that matches what I'm trying to do.

JS
    document.getElementById("BurgerID").addEventListener("click", openNav);

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.zIndex = "995";
    document.getElementById("BurgerID").style.zIndex = "999";
}

if (document.getElementById("overlay").style.transform = "translateX(0%)") {
    document.getElementById("BurgerID").addEventListener("click", closeNav);
}   else {
    document.getElementById("BurgerID").addEventListener("click", openNav);
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.zIndex = "995";
    document.getElementById("BurgerID").style.zIndex = "1";
}
```

Comment: Why not just assign certain class along with these styles?

Comment: You're over complicating this. Just `addClass` that has the properties you want when. You click. And then `hasClass` as your condition to closenav

Comment: share html as well

Comment: I saw your last question and I have an answer, is it related with this one?

Comment: It was, I was trying to find a way to blur everything behind this div in a concise way; was thinking of an if statement that would trigger only if the z-index value was less than ~90.

Answer (score 0):

In your If statement use double or triple equal signs to test if the translate style is applied

```
if (document.getElementById("overlay").style.transform === "translateX(0%)") {
    document.getElementById("BurgerID").addEventListener("click", closeNav);
}   else {
    document.getElementById("BurgerID").addEventListener("click", openNav);
}
```

Comment: This way, you can only open the navigation but you cannot close it once it has been opened.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it this way, but you can toggle the styles in a single eventhandler:

```
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var burger = document.getElementById('BurgerId');

function toggleNav () {
  if (overlay.style.transform === 'translateX(0)') {
    overlay.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
    burger.style.zIndex = 1;
  } else {
    overlay.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
    burger.style.zIndex = 999;
  }
}

burger.addEventListener('click', toggleNav);
```

The main reason why you shouldn't do it with two separate functions is, that you can only open *or* close the navigation, depending on the initial styles applied to it.